Is there a way to create a mesh from edges?
I have a complex structure of which I want to calculate the volume. I tried using the convex hull method, but this does not give me the smallest possible volume as it only takes into account the points, not the lines of the structure. Because of this the volume is always bigger than what it would be in reality.
I am trying to find a way to create a mesh (or something similar) consisting of the points and the lines so that the volume can be calculated in an accurate manner. What would be a good way of doing this?

Do the edges form a connected wireframe, or do you just have an "edge cloud" rather than a point cloud? Do they form planar faces?

@Sneftel Yes they form a connected wireframe.

Are you keeping it a secret whether they form planar faces?
